# Parameters Group on eloquent query

Tags: laravel

I have little problem with my search query at the moment. When i run a search query with only the parameter "comite_id" it's working but when i want to run the search query with "comite_id" and the whereBetween with "date_min" and "date_max" the result is not right , it's seems the result don't care about the whereBetween clause because i don't get the right date range.

Someone knows where i'm doing wrong? thanks a lot in advance

Here my controller :

```
  public function getRetrocession(Request $request){

            $comites = Structure::where('type_structure_id' , '=' ,'3')->pluck('nom_structure' , 'id');

            $search = $request->input('comite_id');
            $dt_min = $request->input('dt_min');
            $dt_max =  $request->input('dt_max');


            if ($search) {
                $query = Retrocession::where('comite_id', '=', $search)

                        ->orWhere(function ($q) use($search , $dt_min , $dt_max) {
                            $q->where('comite_id', '=', $search)
                                ->whereBetween('dt_retrocession', [ $dt_min , $dt_max]);
                        });

            }else {
                $query = Retrocession::select();
            }

            $retrocessions = $query->orderBy('dt_retrocession', 'DESC')->paginate(10)
                ->appends(['recherche' => $search]);

            return view('retrocession/index' , compact('retrocessions' , 'comites'));


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `orWhere()` it always call both `where()` and `orWhere()`; thus including the result of `where()` and `orWhere()`. You can try this way

```
$query = Retrocession::where('comite_id', $search)
->when($dt_min && $dt_max, function($q) use ($dt_min, $dt_max) {
    $q->whereBetween('dt_retrocession', [$dt_min, $dt_max]);
});
```

So you always run the first where, and only include `whereBetween()` WHEN `$dt_min` and `$dt_max` are both true.

Bonne chance Mathieu.